# how can I compare if a drug affects a biological process differently than vehicle treatment

Tags: anova, t-test, biostatistics, jmp

I have an experiment where I am trying to see if a drug has a biological effect that is significantly different from vehicle.  Activity is measured before and after treatment.

For treatment, I have vehicle (control treatment), drug 1 and drug 2. Vehicle has a significant effect on activity (post activity is greater than baseline). Drug 1 also has a significant effect on activity (with post activity even greater than it's baseline). Lastly drug 2 has no effect of activity (post activity is no different than baseline) I now want to compare these effects to each other. I.e. say that drug 1 increases activity even more than vehicle and that drug 2 effectively suppresses activity since it did not increase activity as seen with vehicle.

The interaction term in a mixed linear model will tell me that that these drugs have  different effects on activity compared to baseline, but I want to specifically compare the change from baseline of drug 1 and drug 2 to vehicle.  Do I need to run 2 models?  One with drug 1 vs vehicle, and another with drug 2 vs. vehicle?  I have the model's estimate of mean difference (baseline to drug or vehicle) and st error.  Could I use this to do a T Test? I am using JMP if you have specific suggestions.

Comment: Please explain *vehicle treatment*

Comment: vehicle treatment is a control.  It is the same solution the drug is dissolved in, but without the drug.  In this case, a saline solution

Comment: Please explain *as an edit to the post*. Is this a standard term?

Comment: this is a standard term in any field that uses drugs for a treatment.  I will edit the post.

Answer (score 0):

A simple ANCOVA model should do what you need here. I.e.,

$Y_{post} = \alpha + \beta_1 Y_{pre} + \beta_2 drug1 + \beta_3 drug2 + \epsilon$

The coefficients for drug1 and drug2 will represent the difference in $Y_{post}$ between that treatment and vehicle, adjusted for baseline $Y$.

This model is identical and will tell you the effect of each drug on change in the outcome (relative to vehicle):

$Y_{post} - Y_{pre} = \alpha + \beta_1 Y_{pre} + \beta_2 drug1 + \beta_3 drug2 + \epsilon$